# How to fix no-param-reassign

Tags: javascript, eslint

The following function shows **no-param-reassign error** for `commitMessageClass`.

I wished to know how to solve it. I know I can just close the warning/error in the linter but I need to solve it.

Any ideas?

```
toggleAllCommitMessagesBody(isActive) {
      this.showAllCommitMessageBody = isActive;

      const toRename = this.showAllCommitMessageBody ? 'commit-message message-body active' : 'commit-message message-body';

      const commitMessageClasses = document.getElementsByClassName('commit-message message-body');
      Array.from(commitMessageClasses).forEach((commitMessageClass) => {
        commitMessageClass.className = toRename;
      });

      this.expandedCommitMessagesCount = isActive ? this.totalCommitMessageBodyCount : 0;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean *"solve it"*? Stop assigning to the parameter's property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the properties (i.e. `className` property) on the `commitMessageClass`.

You can use `classList.add()` to avoid doing that.

```js
Array.from(commitMessageClasses).forEach((commitMessageClass) => {
  commitMessageClass.classList.add(toRename);
});
```